# How to insert linebreak when modifying pdf file using iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I was trying to modify a pdf file using iText Java library. I don't know how to put new line after one line. Here is my code. I wish to print "hello" on next line. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the iText 5.5.12 source code (it's open source after all), one quickly finds the following `PdfContentByte` method:

> ```
> /**
>  * Moves to the start of the next line, offset from the start of the current line.
>  *
>  * @param       x           x-coordinate of the new current point
>  * @param       y           y-coordinate of the new current point
>  */
> public void moveText(final float x, final float y)
> ```

Thus, this should do

```
pageContentByte.showText("javawithease.com");
pageContentByte.moveText(0, -20);
pageContentByte.showText("hello");
```

with an assumed line height of 20 user space units.

Alternatively you can use

> ```
> /**
>  * Sets the text leading parameter.
>  * <P>
>  * The leading parameter is measured in text space units. It specifies the vertical distance
>  * between the baselines of adjacent lines of text.</P>
>  *
>  * @param       leading         the new leading
>  */
> public void setLeading(final float leading)
>
> [...]
>
> /**
>  * Moves to the start of the next line.
>  */
> public void newlineText()
> ```

for setting the line height once and then re-using the value:

```
pageContentByte.showText("javawithease.com");
pageContentByte.setLeading(20);
pageContentByte.newlineText();
pageContentByte.showText("hello");
pageContentByte.newlineText();
pageContentByte.showText("hello again");
```

Here you can even combine `newlineText` and `showText` to a single command using

> ```
> /**
>  * Moves to the next line and shows <CODE>text</CODE>.
>  *
>  * @param text the text to write
>  */
> public void newlineShowText(final String text)
> ```

like this:

```
pageContentByte.showText("javawithease.com");
pageContentByte.setLeading(20);
pageContentByte.newlineShowText("hello");
pageContentByte.newlineShowText("hello again");
```

---

This all being said: These are very low-level iText methods corresponding to individual instructions in PDF content streams. Unless you really need to use such low-level routines, you should use at least mid-level classes like `ColumnText` in combination with high-level classes like `Phrase`.

Furthermore, as you appear to just start with iText, you probably should use a current iText version (7.1.x), not a legacy version (5.5.x and below).